# Installing WiFi drivers on a Kali Linux laptop

Tags: kali-linux

I have a Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter. How do I make it work with Kali/Debian Linux?

I can't get my OS to recognize the WiFi connections.

Comment: Try the kali Linux forums https://forums.kali.org/forumdisplay.php?1-Kali-Linux-Forums you may find some good answers there

Comment: Kali is based on Debian so a Debian forum should be able to help you as this question isn't specific to Kali.

Comment: hello sir, let me google this for you...results found: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1286503 -- this is what you need! enjoy! (kali, like back track kali's parent, is based on ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

First download driver [compat-wireless-2.6.30.tar.bz2](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download/stable/).

```
tar -xf compat-wireless-2.6.30.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-2.6.30
make
sudo make install
sudo make unload
```

Then restart OS and install wicd to see if it recognize the wifi adapter...

```
apt-get install wicd
```